# MongoDB: Text Index include non-string data types

Tags: mongodb

How can I create a searchable index based on values that aren't strings? For example:

```
> db.people.ensureIndex({age: 'text', first_name: 'text', last_name:'text', _id:'text'})
> db.people.insert({age: 27, first_name:"Freddie", last_name: "Mercury"})

> db.people.find()[0]
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5441ebe78fe20d0fae7b05b6"), "age" : 27, "first_name" : "Freddie", "last_name" : "Mercury" })

> db.people.find({$text: {$search: '5441ebe78fe20d0fae7b05b6'}})
(no results)
> db.people.find({$text: {$search: '27'}})
(no results)
```

I'd like to create a searchable index based on a few keys, but some of those are NumberLong, ObjectId, etc. $search requires a string. A client may also send a query like `"27 Freddie"`. Can I force the index to cast all values to strings, for the sake of this indexing/searching?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds strange for me that someone would use something like '27 Freddie' as a search term and I would rather allow the user to provide different fields: age, first name, last name.

In your case I would create additional field in which I would incorporate all text searchable fields and add a search text index on it. For example:

```
{
  age: 27,
  first_name:"Freddie",
  last_name: "Mercury",
  search : '27 Freddie Mercury'
}
```

Comment: True, that combining fields would be unlikely, however, being able to search for 'freddie mercury' (combining fields), but not able to for integer fields seems unintuitive to a client.
Including a search field manually would work, but tough to maintain during updates. Ex: what if a kay/val pair is removed, should the `search` index fail? Do I generate a whole new index string each time even one field is updated? These are just a couple problems that mongo has already solved for the most part (text-indexes are sparse by default).